# Voting on "On Hold" questions

Tags: discussion, voting, on-hold

This is a short one. I'm not really strongly for this idea, just wanted to know why it works like this...

If a question is "On Hold" is it right that I should be able to up/downvote it? Doesn't the fact it's On Hold mean that the question is, in its current state, unacceptable for Stack Overflow? Rendering any up/downvotes to the contrary a bit redundant?

Just seems like an invitation to downvote a poor question into oblivion, then run off without reversing the vote even if the user fixed the issues.

Comment: I always thought the same thing but never this loud

Comment: ...and woe unto the user who does edit it and make it a better, if not good, question.  If it does get reopened, the negative votes keep good-question hunters from bothering too look at it.

Comment: Consider that a question that is on hold and is edited into shape. It is still on hold. Should it not get, in its current form, any upvotes?

Comment: @Oded Wouldn't have thought so. Shouldn't the user vote to reopen instead?

Comment: Conversely, consider a *really bad* question that gets put on hold with less than three downvotes. Adding further downvotes allow trusted users to vote for deletion, locking that would always require moderator action.

Comment: Instead? Why not both?

Comment: Because it's "On Hold"? When it's not "On Hold" you should be able to do with it as you please, no? @FrédéricHamidi I can see this being more of a factor, I didn't know that's the way it worked.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-or-on-hold-question

Comment: From the point of view of question ban, getting out of - allowing the question to sit there gathering more downvotes makes it harder for the user to clean up their act once they learn how to ask.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Questions should be evaluated in the state that they are currently in when you encounter them.  It's too difficult to constantly monitor questions for improvements, and we're not set up for that anyway.  So it behooves questions askers to try and get their question right the first time.

The right way to prevent downvotes on closed questions would be to remove those questions from the front page when they are closed.  That way, you're not taking up community members' valuable time evaluating these questions.

But since the community can see closed questions, and must spend time looking at them to evaluate them (even as a candidate for reopening), then I think they have a right to vote on them, regardless of their open/closed state.

Comment: So... Remove them from the home page then.

Comment: And how would one do that, exactly?

Comment: if (mything.isclosed()) continue;

Comment: How then does the post get its reopen vote after editing, so that it can be be thrown into the reopen queue, if nobody sees it?

Comment: OP can edit his crap into gold if s?he wants, otherwise it's not worth hand-holding h(im|er).